# where clause not working for special characters in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopback

I am trying to upsert with where in loopback.

The query fails for

```
https://api.flowace.in/alpha/v1/Devices/upsertWithWhere?where={"deviceId": "34:8B:75:A8:CE:9D"}&access_token=Ygdfbidsvbdiwg9ZHhE1l93sdlvmkdlknv
```

It gives the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

However it works perfectly when i remove the : from the string

```
https://api.flowace.in/alpha/v1/Devices/upsertWithWhere?where={"deviceId": "mysampleId"}&access_token=Ygdfbidsvbdiwg9ZHhE1l93sdlvmkdlknv
```

Answer (score 0):

Please stringify your JSON params if you are sending as a query parameter as there is no error with query, below is the sample code :

```
   model.upsertWithWhere(
        {
            deviceId: "34:8B:75:A8:CE:9D"
        },
        {
            created: new Date(),
            deviceId: "34:8B:75:A8:CE:9D",
        },
        (err, res) => {

        });
```

Comment: I am using it in url. What I have been able to find till now is the issue happens when the string start with a number

Comment: First of all you have to give two params for using upsertWithWhere clause. One is "where" and other is "data".

Now your url for type POST will be like:
https://api.flowace.in/alpha/v1/Devices/upsertWithWhere?where=%7B%22deviceId%22%3A%20%2234%3A8B%3A75%3AA8%3ACE%3A9D%22%7D&access_token=xWG1zGoGu3skw9jU86ja7mzoXWSVdXC4JC1DBKy0TI72OI7GztupoyeGDbtslCsO


Please replace accessToken in url.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> The reason is that your request URL is not being parsed as a correct
>   URL format.

You can use this parsed URL for loopback query.

```
https://api.flowace.in/alpha/v1/Devices/upsertWithWhere?where=%7B%22deviceId%22%3A%2234:8B:75:A8:CE:9D%22%7D&access_token=Ygdfbidsvbdiwg9ZHhE1l93sdlvmkdlknv
```

Please refer this table for symbol matching:

```
{  =>  %7B
"  =>  %22
:  =>  %3A
@  =>  %40
}  =>  %7D
```

Comment: it is still not working, it gives the same error, I am guessing, postman autoencodes those : anyways

Comment: What I have been able to find till now is the issue happens when the string start with a number. When I add ID: to id string, it start working correctly,